# Crystal report stack 2 column header in crosstab

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

Here is my problem.  I have crystal 12.1 connected to an access database.  I would like to create a crosstab to compare current year sales with prior year.  I was able to create the initial cross tab, but I cannot figure out how to add the year(s) under the store name.  Here is what I would like it too look like. (CY is current year, PY is prior year)

```
           Store 1      Store2     Store3    ...            
           ----------   ---------  --------  
            CY   PY      CY   PY    CY   PY  
Toys         2    3       4    3     7    7    
Clothes      1    4       3    8     8    2
Shoes        2    2       4    5     6    9
```

I have the store name and CY salses in the crosstab now.  I have no idea how to add the the PY header and values.  My crosstab has the Store in the columns and the summarized fields have the Toys, Clothes, Shoes, etc values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add your date field into the columns area of the cross-tab expert (below the store field).

The highlight and click group options, set it to group on year.

Comment: When I add the date field, it gives me 2012 then a total column, after all of the 2012 data is listed then the report starts again at 2011